# Toast displayed in HTC Nexus One and not working with Samsung Fame

Tags: android, toast

I try to display a Toast.

```
Toast.makeText(this, "HOLA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And it doesn't appear...
Even if I put it just after onCreate(), on the almost first instruction......

I call it in the mainActivity. It was working before in my app....

EDIT: It seems that in another phone, toast are displaying well, But I can't get it work anyway. It is working with a HTC Nexus One ( API 10), but won't work with a Samsung Fame ( API 14)

Comment: Please post the code. It always helps. Please also show how you're calling what I can only assume to be an AsyncTask.

Comment: Yes, pls post the code...in your line here, there is no issue seen so, it might be something else in the rest of the code. I believe you are using AsyncTask in this case.

Comment: Question updated. I tried to clean the unnessecary code, and I let all OnPostExecute.

Comment: Try using `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HOLA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: It's not working. I tried to use getApplicationContext(), this, MapActivity.this, and nothing works... Before it was working without problems.

Comment: Try --> Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "HOLA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro Is that `Log("","");` displaying?

Comment: getBaseContext() not working, Log is working well

Comment: Post the entire method where you are trying to call the Toast(). The code I posted 100% works, it will be in the context of when or where you are making the Toast() call.

Comment: the whole method is more than 500 lines, it is difficult, but I put it just after onCreate, and I can't see it. I don't think it is the syntaxis, because it was working well before.

Comment: They are not talking about the sintaxis. They are talking about your Toast line code is never being called. With 500 lines in a single method, it is quite possible. It would be helpful if you post where on your code you are using the line you posted up there, even better how deep it is (inside any if statement?).

Comment: Post some more code, where r u invoking `toast` message

Comment: Can you tell which class are you extending like `XXXActiviy extends ...`?

Comment: Yes, it extends SherlockFragmentActivity

Answer (score 0):

Try using Activity Name in context like this

```
Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, "HOLA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Activity Name in context like this

```
Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, "HOLA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Or

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HOLA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

or

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "HOLA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Or

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "HOLA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```